# How to convert cocos2d-x android project to c++ in eclipse ADT

Tags: eclipse, adt, cocos2d-x

Hi I'm fairly new with Eclipse. I'm trying to work on my cocos2d-x project on Eclipse, but for some reason I couldn't convert the android project to a c/c++ project and so I couldn't open the c++ files inside the Classes folders as you can see on the image [here](http://s21.postimg.org/osfvzhnfr/cannot_convert_to_a_c_project.jpg).

- **cocos2d-x:** cocos2d-x v3.0 alpha0
- **eclipse:** (ADT)Android Developer Tools - Build: v22.2.1-833290
- **os:** windows 7

What I did:

1. ran create-multi-platform-projects.py in cmd
2. opened eclipse(ADT) then File->New->Other->Android Project from Existing Code->browsed to {cocos2d-x v3}/projects/mygame/proj.android
3. built the project.
4. tried to convert the project. Right-clicked project->New->Other->Under C/C++ tree, select Convert to a C/C++ project (Adds C/C++ nature)

but then the candidates for conversion is empty, meaning I couldn't convert my project to c++. I have installed the C++ plugins as seen [here](http://s16.postimg.org/oaacsci9h/ADT_plugins.jpg). Obviously I'm missing something here but I can't figure out what. I've been following tutorials on setting up cocos2d-x android development on eclipse windows os but I'm stuck with the converting to c++ step. Please could someone point out what I'm missing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will already be having c++ nature, so it wont show you that option (You can verify this by checking if you have C/C++ build in your project properties)...

You can open the cpp files by adding a reference to the source folder, to do so follow the below steps:

1. Right Click your project and select properties
2. Goto Resource->Linked Resources
3. In Path Variables Tab, Click New...
4. Give some name and choose the folder where you have your source code

It will now show a link to the source code folder in the project

Comment: Thanks! You're right, my project is already a C/C++. Although your steps did not exactly resolve my problem, it led me to it. Resource->Linked Resources under Linked Resources tab, the default location of the cpp files starts with the variable COCOS2DX which is not defined under Path Variables tab. After defining COCOS2DX variable to points to cocos2d-x root directory, I can now open the cpp files. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://deepakgautam.com.np/2013/11/16/building-cocos2d-x-project-in-eclipse/) are one by one steps, You may setup easily!

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.